# MUL Instruction in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, multiplication

I am having difficulties figuring out what the result of the below operation would be. After doing research online and referencing my 80x86 book, it looks likes the mul instruction always references the ax register.

The 'mul  ecx' instruction is executed starting with the register values below:

```
EAX:  00 00 00 10
ECX:  FF FF  FF FD
EDX:  FF 03 FF 01
```

How is ecx calculated? I understand that the mul instruction is "mul ", but *what is it actually multiplying by*?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `mul ecx` instruction doesn't modify `ecx`. The value in ecx is an input, not an output. (Also, this question is tagged x86-16, but there is no ecx register in x86-16.)

Comment: @RaymondChen There is.  x86-16 just means real mode / 16-bit protected mode, not no 386 extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it looks likes the mul instruction always references the `ax` register.

The x86 `mul` instruction always multiplies the accumulator register (`EAX`, `AX`, or `AL`) by whichever operand you provide in the instruction:

- The **dword-sized** `mul ecx` will multiply EAX with ECX and leave its double-length product in the register combo EDX:EAX.
- The **word-sized** `mul cx` will multiply AX with CX and leave its double-length product in the register combo DX:AX.
- The **byte-sized** `mul cl` will multiply AL with CL and leave its double-length product in the register
  AX.

All three versions are available in the real address mode of any x86, but the first version (`mul ecx`) does not exist on [8086](/questions/tagged/8086).

On x86-64 there's also a **qword-sized** `mul rcx` that will multiply RAX with RCX and leave its double-length product in the register combo RDX:RAX.

> How is `ecx` calculated?

The operand in `mul ecx` is not modified in any way. It's a given that you need to initialize beforehand.